# Why is Stripe missing payment method?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have tried to use Stripe connect to take a fee of a purchases on my site it works fine as long as the payments are just supposed to be for my own Stripe account itself.
I'm getting the message "The customer has not entered their payment method."

I have tried searching through the Stripe docs but haven't found exactly what i needed perhaps i'm looking under the wrong topic as i'm very new to Stripe.

Does somebody has an idea of what i'm doing wrong? What should this "payment method" be set as?

EDIT:

I store customer token in mysql and the same for account_id for connected account.

```
$charge = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => 100,
  'currency' => 'USD',
  'customer' => 'cus_token_here',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'application_fee_amount' => 12,
  'transfer_data' => [
    'destination' => 'acct_token_here',
  ],
]);
```

Comment: The error sounds like the Customer identified by that cus_token_here, doesn't have a PaymentMethod. It's weird given the fact that you don't pass confirm=true. But it would be easier to grasp the errored request id (req_xxx) and contact Stripe Support and then can check for you

Comment: I am not familiar with the transfer_data abd connected accounts. Seems as though you should be including a payment_method for the payment intent. Have you collected a payment method or card details from the customer using payment elements?